# How to display QR code image in React image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, qr-code

I'm trying to implement 2fa on my app

I used speakeasy and QRCode library in my backend which is nodejs api

In the process of creating a QRCode, the backend returns an image for the user to scan it through his phone and activate the feature in his account

I know that I have another option and make the api return an code and not an image, but I think that returning an image of the frontend is better from a security point of view, correct me if I am wrong

**update**

I updated my code so that the backend sends the link instead of the image

**this code nodejs**

```
const GenerateOTP = async (req, res) => {
  try {


   let loginUser = { _id: req.user.id };
   let foundUserLogin = await dbService.findOne(User, loginUser);

    //check user find
    if (!foundUserLogin) {
      return res.badRequest({
        message: "not user",
      });
  }

  const  user_id  = foundUserLogin.id;
    const {base32, otpauth_url } = speakeasy.generateSecret({
      issuer: "codevoweb.com",
      name: "admin@admin.com",
      length: 15,
    });


     // Update otp
     const dataTo = {
      otp_auth_url: (otpauth_url),
      otp_base32: (base32),
    };
    await User.updateOne(
      { _id: user_id },
      { $set: dataTo },
      { new: true }
    );

  let Generate = {base32, otpauth_url}
   return res.success({ data :Generate});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "error",
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "error",
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

On the frontend, I'm trying to display this image on a component in React, but I'm failing

Below I show you my code
This is what is being received in the response on React

**this component**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback ,useEffect} from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {  ModalBody,
    ModalHeader, Button, Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Col, Container, Form, Input, Label, Modal, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Row, TabContent, TabPane } from 'reactstrap';
import classnames from "classnames";
import Flatpickr from "react-flatpickr";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
//import images
import progileBg from '../../../assets/images/profile-bg.jpg';
import avatar1 from '../../../assets/images/users/avatar-1.jpg';
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Create2fa,validate2Fa } from "../../../store/actions";
import Otp2faHook from "../../../Hooks/Otp2faHook/Otp2fahook";



const Settings = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [res2fa,lode,error,res2faitem] = Otp2faHook();
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("1");
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);
    const tabChange = (tab) => {
        if (activeTab !== tab) setActiveTab(tab);
    };



 // validation
 const validation = useFormik({
    // enableReinitialize : use this flag when initial values needs to be changed
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
     
        token: "",
     
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
        token: Yup.number().required("code required"),
      
    }),
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      const validate2Facode = {
      
      
        token: values["token"],
      };
      setloading(true);
      
      dispatch(validate2Fa(validate2Facode));
      
      setloading(false);
      
      
      validation.resetForm();
    //  toggle();
    },

  });



    const toggle = useCallback(() => {
      
        if (modal) {
          setModal(false);
        } else {
          setModal(true);
        }
      }, [modal]);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (modal === true) {
          dispatch(Create2fa());
        }  
      }, [dispatch, modal]);

    document.title="Profile Settings | Velzon - React Admin & Dashboard Template";

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="page-content">
                <Container fluid>

<Modal
          isOpen={modal}
          toggle={toggle}
          centered
          size="lg"
          className="border-0"
          modalClassName="zoomIn"
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggle} className="p-3 bg-soft-info">
            {"2fa"}
          </ModalHeader>
          <Form
            className="was-validated"
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              validation.handleSubmit();
              return false;
            }}
          >
            <ModalBody>
              <Row className="g-3">
                <Col lg={12}>
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <Label htmlFor="validationLabel" className="form-label">
                      scan
                    </Label>
                    <img alt="" src={res2faitem} /> //How to display QR code image
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row className="g-3">
                <Col lg={12}>
                  <div className="mb-3">
                    <Label htmlFor="validationLabel" className="form-label">
                      test
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      className="form-control is-invalid"
                      name="token"
                      id="validationInput"
                      placeholder=""
                      onChange={validation.handleChange}
                      onBlur={validation.handleBlur}
                      value={validation.values.token || ""}
                      required
                    ></Input>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </ModalBody>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <div className="hstack gap-2 justify-content-end">
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    setModal(false);
                  }}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-light"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  exit
                </button>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" id="add-btn">
                  {"send "}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Modal>
        <ToastContainer closeButton={false} />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

[image]

Comment: No, you're wrong. Sending an image to the client instead of the qr code text itself will not make it more secure. it just makes coding harder.

Comment: Sending the qr as a text to the client opens more opportunities to the client to consume it. For example, you can change how the QR looks like in the client, some people might want to use your API, it's not only your web app which is going to consume that API, other people might want to consume that API in the future, who knows.

Comment: What if the client wanted for example to change the size of that QR code? The width and the height of the image? That would break the resolution. Or in another case, what if the client wanted to apply another theme for the app? Ex: dark mode, crazy yellow on green theme or so on. Having the QR code printed on a white background isn't always the best looking view.

Comment: And later, what if there was some programmatic way to read that QR, instead of a camera reading it, for example, two APIs talking to each another? These APIs will need to have the text of the QR, not the image, because computers will not read the image to export the QR text from, that's simply just… Not how things should be organized to do.

Comment: @Normal Thank you dear for replying
I am very concerned about security
In any case, as long as you say there is no security problem in sending the code instead of the image
I will edit the question and update the code
Please stay close

Comment: OK, so what's the problem you're having in the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

Use react-qr-code, pass one of the generated properties of the generated object from speakeasy into the value prop of the QR jsx.

```
<QRCode
   size={256}
   style={{ height: "auto", maxWidth: "100%", width: "100%" }}
   value={"speakeasy base32 String"}
   viewBox={`0 0 256 256`}
/>
```